# I got a TypeError message when using tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

When I use tensorflow RNN, I met this problem.
Here is the version of my package:

```
Python version: 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

Packages versions: 
numpy 1.12.1
tensorflow 1.1.0
```

And the code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn

batches = 28

permutations = np.random.permutation(batches)

cell_class = rnn.BasicLSTMCell
cell = cell_class(200)
zero_state = cell.zero_state(batches, tf.float32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    state = sess.run(zero_state)
    state[np.arange(batches)] = state[permutations]
```

The message I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    state[np.arange(batches)] = state[permutations]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try replacing `zero_state` value with below line:

```
zero_state = cell.zero_state(batches, tf.float32)[0]
```

This appears to be an issue with the latest version of Numpy. A recent change made it an error to treat a single-element array as a scalar for the purposes of indexing.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is really caused by the latest Numpy. I solve it by adding `[0]` after `state` : )